# Log all REST API requests before they arrive at a viewset

Tags: django, logging, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to log all REST requests that arrive at the Django REST framework API.  I want to log the response of API calls too.
Where can I define my function that logs all REST API requests and responses?

Comment: Ideally we will need to log request and response of an api call together. Having separate process_request and process_response will not handle this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589907/how-to-log-request-and-response-for-4xx-http-status-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [write a Django middleware component](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to intercept traffic into and out of the application.

There will be two methods, `process_response` and `process_request`. Use each one to log the response and request, respectively.

```python
class LoggingMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        # do your logging here

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # do your logging here
```

But this will log all requests and responses, not only to the specific API.  If you want to log only API ones, you can easily check the URL in this method for prefix like `/api` and log info based on this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did the following and got 500 error.. I'm not sure what is wrong.  
class MyMiddleware():
    def process_request( self, request ):

        <Log request>

        return Response( status=status.HTTP_200_OK )



    def process_response( self, request, response ):

        <Log info>

        return Response( status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
Do you find anything amiss?

Comment: it should return None not a Response if u want only logging. And whats is in logs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code works.
class MyMiddleware(): 
    def process_request( self, request ): 
        print "xxxxx"
        return None
    def process_response( self, request, response ): 
        print "xxxxx" 
        return response

Comment: The code works fine.  But, the request.user doesn't have the actual username.  As per my code, the user is populated only after hitting the authentication classes.  As I see, the middleware classes are called before authentication classes.  Are there any set of classes that are called after authentication and from which I can log the REST api?

Comment: @linuxfreak u just need to move this middleware below auth middleware in the list

Answer (score -1):

This depends on your how you want to log the information and how you have build your API.

For something simple try looking into [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

Your API must take some sort of input of the query, so wrap that in a log

```
callAPI(query)    
logging.info(query)
```

and the same with your API return

```
return APIJSONanswer
logging.info(APIJSONanswer)
```

Comment: I'm familiar with logging module.  But, my point is I don't want to call logging.info in each viewset.  If there is a common function that gets called before the call is routed to each viewset, I can just call logging.info there.

Comment: There should be. It depends on your build though. I can't get more specific before I know more about you setup.

Comment: Is there a common function in django framework that gets hit before going to a viewset?