# How to log request and response for 4XX Http status in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, logging, django-rest-framework, django-logging

The default behaviour of DRF is to throw exception for 5XX, but return valid response with error details for 4XX. I want to log request and response of any API call which fails with 4XX.

Currently the log only shows `Bad Request : /path/api/`

Answer: Custom exception work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own custom exception handler and access your request such as:

```py
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code
        response.data['request'] = context['request']

    return response
```

And show your custom handler in `settings.py` such as:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```